# jQuery errors MaterializeCSS

Tags: jquery, laravel, materialize

I'm working with materialize CSS framework. I suddenly got a bunch of errors  and I can't display modals, selects, parallax anymore on my website.

I'm using the functions that are included in the documentation.

These are the errors:

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).parallax is not a 
     function TypeError: $(...).parallax is not a function
      at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/home:623:22)
     at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:29999)
     at k (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:30313) undefined
      r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
      jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: 
 $(...).material_select is not a function TypeError: $(...).material_select 
 is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/home:632:17)
at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:29999)
at k (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:30313) undefined
 r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
  jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).collapsible is not 
  a function TypeError: $(...).collapsible is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8000/home:637:23)
at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:29999)
at k (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2:30313) undefined
 r.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2
 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parallax is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (home:623)
at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).material_select is not a 
function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (home:632)
at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
 jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).collapsible is not a 
 function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (home:637)
at j (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
at k (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2)
```

And this is my JS file:

```
     <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.14.0/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>





     <script>

                $(document).ready(function(){
              $('.parallax').parallax();
            });


            $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({fullWidth: true});



                 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('select').material_select();
          });


          $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.collapsible').collapsible();
          });


         // Or with jQuery

         $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.modal').modal();
          });

       </script>
```

This is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using multiple document.ready()

Comment: I wrapped them in only one and I'm getting always the same errors..

Comment: you define this link in header???

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Are you connected to the Internet? 
Or maby the cdn addresses you are using are wrong

Comment: yes I'm connected sure...
it was working normally from a while, I got this error just today!

Comment: the code is fine try **ctrl+f5** or **ctrl+r** or clear browser caches